# Extracting a value after a substring in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

So I have a string that looks like this

```
.AW 40 fork spam eggs
.CD 60.FR 70 pumpkin candy
.BO odd blue berry mops
```

In this string, I'm trying to extract the numerical value after the substrings `.AW` `.CD` `.FR`and the  word `odd`after `.BO` In python. I thought of splitting the string, putting the remaining string after each code in another string and then extracting the first few values in that string, which would be the numerical values or the word odd.I just wanted to know if there was a more convenient way of doing this. The numbers could be any random numbers so I'd have to assume I don't know what they would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This one assumes, you always want the word/number right after the word that starts with `.`.*

Just use a `for` loop. That'd be probably the easiest and understandable way of doing this.

```
strings = [".AW 40 fork spam eggs",".CD 60.FR 70 pumpkin candy",".BO odd blue berry mops"]
for your_string in strings
    for ss in your_string.split("."):
        if ss:
            print(ss.split()[1])

#Or with a one-liner
[ss.split()[1] for your_string in strings for ss in your_string.split(".") if ss]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.